# Add a transparent view above an image view using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i have a UIImageView .i want to add a trans

```
 inCallBackGroundImgae = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"caller_texture.png"]];
        [inCallBackGroundImgae setFrame:CGRectMake(0,top, self.view.frame.size.width, 250)];
        [self.view addSubview: inCallBackGroundImgae];
```

[image]

i want to add a transparent view, where i add a red colour [image] .i don,t want navigation bar i want to add a transparent view

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly `hide navigation bar` like this in `viewDidLoad method`

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
```

Now add your transparent `UIView` in place of `navigationBar`

```
UIView *transparentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64)];
transparentView.alpha = 0.33f;
[self.view addSubview: transparentView];
```

**EDIT** : Adjust your image view frame as transparent view will not be seen.

```
CGRect imgViewRect = inCallBackGroundImgae.frame;
imgViewRect.origin.y = 64;
imgViewRect.size.height = decrease height here if necessary
inCallBackGroundImgae.frame = imgViewRect;
```

Comment: it's not working ... no transparent view added :(

Comment: Check edited answer made some changes

Comment: Don't hide navigation bar. Instead make it transparent . 
Then add your red subview using  [self.navigationController.view addSubview:redView]; Or directly adding subview will also work. No need of making navigation bar transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Please do this one

```
UIView *transView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];// set your height here what ever you wanna.
    transView.alpha = 0.5f;// set your alpha how much you wanna transparent.
[inCallBackGroundImgae addSubview: transView];
```